# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=3.1.0.0

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

I am converting a Asp.net Core 3.0 **to asp.net core 3.1**. Everything works fine from visual studio 2019. However when I publish a deployment package and execute the web application from IIS I get the following error message: 
Application startup exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

**Nuget package used**: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
**Packages Installed**: Microsoft.Net Core.1.0 - Windows Server Hosting, Microsoft.Net Core - 3.1.0 Preview 3 (x64), Microsoft.Net Core SDK 3.1.100(x64) from visual studio

**IIS**:  Version 6.1 (Build 7601 Service Pack1)

Comment: IIS Version is actually: Version 7.5.7600.16385

Comment: Please check if the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll` file is existing under the folder of your published app/package. And you can try to [republish your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#publish-and-deploy-the-app) and check if it can help fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem, turns out I had to clean the output folder.
`/bin/Release` contained netcoreapp3.0 and netcoreapp3.1 and somehow it got mixed up.
I just cleaned the sources in Azure DevOps and tried again and it worked.